# How do define anonymous functions in C++?

Tags: c++, function, syntax, inline

Can I define functions in C++ inline? I am talking about lambda functions, not the `inline` keyword that causes a compiler optimization.

Comment: I believe in the new C++11 syntax, lambdas might provide something similar to what you wish to achieve?

Comment: Yeah, in C++11, to pass one that adds two ints it'd be `[](int num1, int num2) {return num1 + num2);}`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Comment: what if I need to: `int n = 1==2?function(){return 10;} : -1;` something like that?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

C++11 added [lambda functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C++_(since_C++11)) to the language.  The previous versions of the language (C++98 and C++03), as well as all current versions of the C language (C89, C99, and C11) do not support this feature.  The syntax looks like:

```
[capture](parameters)->return-type{body}
```

For example, to compute the sum of all of the elements in a vector:

```
std::vector<int> some_list;
int total = 0;
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) some_list.push_back(i);
std::for_each(begin(some_list), end(some_list), [&total](int x) {
  total += x;
});
```

Comment: `int total = std::accumulate(begin(some_list), end(some_list), 0);` :)

Comment: Any particular reason this was downvoted? It answers the question just fine.

Comment: Isn't the code missing a `mutable`? IIRC lambdas take captures as `const` by default, so it should be `[&total](int x) mutable`.

Comment: @Grizzly: That's only interesting for by-value captures, since `const`ness doesn't propagate through indirection.

Comment: Where is `begin(...)` and `end(...)` are defined? Are they macros for vector.begin() and vector.end() ?

Comment: @Desolator : They're in namespace `std`, found by ADL. And yes, they wrap `some_list.begin()` and `some_list.end()` in this case.

Comment: note that polymorphic lambdas are not part of c++11

Answer (score 36):

In C++11, you can use closures:

```
void foo()
{
   auto f = [](int a, int b) -> int { return a + b; };

   auto n = f(1, 2);
}
```

Prior to that, you can use local classes:

```
void bar()
{
   struct LocalClass
   {
       int operator()(int a, int b) const { return a + b; }
   } f;

   int n = f(1, 2);
}
```

Both versions can be made to refer to ambient variables: In the local class, you can add a reference member and bind it in the constructor; and for the closure you can add a *capture list* to the lambda expression.

Comment: Remember that you can't use local types in templates prior to C++11.

Comment: @Xeo: That's true, but I didn't think that was a requirement... the OP is welcome to clarify.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean it that way. It was a general reminder, since you didn't mention that restriction.

Comment: Neither of your examples form closures. The first example does form an anonymous function though.

Comment: @ThomasEding: That depends on your personal disposition towards the empty set, I suppose.

Answer (score 10):

i dont know if i understand you well, but you want a lambda function?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>


    int main()
    {
        std::vector<int> c { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
        int x = 5;
        c.erase(std::remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), [x](int n) { return n < x; } ), c.end());

        std::cout << "c: ";
        for (auto i: c) {
            std::cout << i << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

        std::function<int (int)> func = [](int i) { return i+4; };
        std::cout << "func: " << func(6) << '\n'; 
    }
```

if you dont have c++11x then try:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/lambda.html

Answer (score 8):

Pre C++11, if you want to *localize* a function to a function, that can be done:

```
int foo () {
    struct Local {
        static int bar () {
            return 1;
        }
    };
    return Local::bar();
}
```

or if you want something more complicated:

```
int foo (int x) {
    struct Local {
        int & x;
        Local (int & x) : x(x) {}
        int bar (int y) {
            return x * x + y;
        }
    };
    return Local(x).bar(44);
}
```

But if you want a true function literal in pre C++11, that is not possible.